# Handle click on a row and/or a cell of a datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, onclick

I have placed a `Datagrid` control on my `WPF` application and I'm trying to handle the mouse right `click event` on a row or a single cell of my `Datagrid` control. How can I achieve it? I've tried to capture the event with `selectedItem` executing the method but its not working "`ciao`"

Below is the `xaml` code:

```
<TabItem Header="Lista Dipendenti">
                <DataGrid x:Name="gridListaDipendenti" Margin="64,42,73,65"  SelectedItem="ciao"/>
</TabItem>
```

I wish I could execute some code when the user clicks a row or cell of the `Datagrid` and possibly get the value of the row (the ID).

Comment: That's not so easy :)
Look this http://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html

Answer (score 1):

In visual basic, if you want to access the `numberOfTheColum` element of the `numberOfTheRow` row:

```
dataGridObject.Items(numberOfTheRow).Row(numberOfTheColum)
```

Besides that, there is a event called `MouseRightButtonUp` or something like that:

```
MouseRightButtonUp="methodName"
```

In that method name is where you can access the datagrid elements or even the cell pressed with `datagridObject.CurrentCell`

Hope it help